# Error while deploying the spring boot app in tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8.5

**I am trying to deploy spring boot app on tomcat server but getting error as SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive**

Here is the POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-web-application-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.springboot.MainApp</start-class>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->
    <!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>1.0.1.Final</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <!--        <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>  -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.185</version>
        <!-- $NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JSTL tag lib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tomcat for JSP rendering -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>


    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your response. As i am new to spring boot , i am unaware of right stuff. could you please help me in cleaning them and make it work. Thanks

Comment: Mixing versions of hibernate, spring, overriding managed versions etc. In short remove all your `org.hibernate` dependencies, remove the `spring` (the 2.5 one) dependency. Remove all `version` tags as Spring Boot will manage those for you .

Answer (score 2):

Use https://start.spring.io/ to create your initial POM / Spring Boot application.

You can add dependencies later as required.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are trying to run your application on local. 
Spring boot application has inbuilt tomcat server. 
In order to run your application in eclipse, 
    1) Right click on your project --> 2) Go to Run as --> 3) Java application
Your application will start.

Add dependency of devTools as well in your pom, so that if you make any changes in your code the server will be restarted automatically.

Answer (score -1):

you do not need to deploy spring-boot project in tomcat, spring-boot is having is own server to run the application.
so when you deploy application on server, with the help of maven we can build and run the spring-boot application.
here is the command to run build and run the application in linux.

```
nohup mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

if you want to restart server you need to kill port id

```
lsof -i : appPortNumber 

kill -9 processIdOfPort
```